# Sorry! board game in C++

Tags: c++, oop

I was trying to implement the [Sorry! board](http://www.flickr.com/photos/15683948@N00/1225290276/) game using C++ such that 4 players (Includes computer as one of the player) could play the game over a network and there is also a score board and a message board for the players to chat.

The main idea is to crystallize my understanding of C++ and use almost all OOP concepts while implementing this game.

I was trying divide the problem into classes and had 2 questions:
1. Each player green, yellow, blue, red have 4 pieces each. Is each piece a class or green1class, green2 class ..... or is it just that each color is a class and each piece of the same color is just an instance of the class.
2. Also How do I start dividing a generic problem like this into classes?

Comment: Sounds you like you don't really have a question but need a good book on C++ OOP. Overall it sounds like you would need a SorryGame class, a SorryPlayer class, and a SorryPiece class. The SorryPiece class would have attributes that determine what color it is, or which player it belongs to for example.

Comment: Despite this question being closed, don't let people discourage you.  A Sorry game is as good a goal as any.  But you should avoid mentioning on StackOverflow that you hope to make it networked and have in-game AI someday.  (Such ambition from someone who doesn't know much about their target language is derided...not admired.)  In any case, the advice to go through and work some simpler samples like out of *Thinking in C++* is good, you will stand on a much firmer foundation to contemplate questions like the one you're asking here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start thinking in objects, and in a "is a" and "has a" manner kind of like this:

A game piece is an object

A player is another object.
  A player has 4 game pieces.
  A player has a color

A gameboard is an object.
  A gameboard has spaces.
  A gameboard has 4 players

And so on.  As you get used to thinking in a "is a" and "has a" manner, it gets easier.

Also try to break down things to the lowest level - if every player has a color, then maybe player should be an object that has a color, instead of 4 player objects based on color

Do this (I know this is not proper c/c++ code, but it demonstrates the ides):

```
class Player
{
 string Color;
 Piece[] Pieces[4];
}
```

instead of

```
class RedPlayer
{
 RedPieceOne Piece1
 RedPieceTwo Piece2
}
class GreenPlayer
{
}
```

etc.